# What is the 'standard' concerning style guidelines in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

First of all, I'd like to say that I'm not trying to start a discussion on what is the best coding style.

Rather, I was wondering what is actually the global standard when it comes to styling your code. I've seen different websites and mainly open source organisations which have their own guideline page, which for example says that you should put `} else {` on the same line.

Are there some (un)written rules concerning code style which apply to all JavaScript being written? Is there a common preference for specific coding styles? Or is this really on a per-organisation basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one standard. Are there any guidelines out there that you can follow if you want to keep your code consistent? How about google's coding style? http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

We use that as basic guidelines at our company

Answer (score 2):

These are widely accepted*:

- Variable names contain only characters a-zA-Z_ (and sometimes $0-9)
- Indent by 4 spaces or a tab character (Never mix!)
- Constructor functions begin with an uppercase letter
- Terminate every statement with a semicolon
- [Egyptian bracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2801919#2801919)
- always use blocks in after `if`, `else`, etc., even for a single statement
- One space after a comma, no space before
- Assignment/comparison operators are surrounded by spaces
- Avoid lines containing multiple statements
- Use `'` as a string delimiter

From my experience, most conventions are subject to heated discussions.
So, no, there is no general rule. Some people even [try to completely avoid semicolons](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)

---

* or are they? ;)

Comment: Widely accepted by you :)  I agree they seem like good guidelines, but really at then end, you just need to agree on something so that your team can work together consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) is widely used as a basis for coding guidelines.

His [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) tool can be used to check whether code meets his recommendations.

Comment: I think OP was more concerned about style, not actual programming practices

Comment: I was indeed wondering about the formatting, but thanks for your reply nevertheless.

Comment: There are some style guidelines on Crockford's website: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: Crockford's book does contain a lot of "style" stuff, like where to put opening braces, whether to use semicolons, where to put your `var` declrations, etc., although he does concentrate on practical concerns rather than aesthetics.

Answer (score -1):

[Standard](https://github.com/feross/standard) is the new standard.

[image: js-standard-style]

I've been using it in all my projects.